# Storing JWT tokens for Flutter web

Tags: flutter, dart, jwt, flutter-web

I receive a JWT token from my express backend in my flutter web app. But in order for not letting the user login again the next time I would need to persist the token.
As I already read it is not advised to store those tokens in the localStorage and the secureStorage from Android is not available for web.

So what would be the best practice to do so?

Answer (score 1):

you can use [SharedPreferences](https://pub.dev/packages/shared_preferences_web) for the web to store your jwt. shared preferences is a key-value structure that helps you to save and restore your values.

Comment: But this just stores the data in localStorage on Web. So there is no difference.

Comment: I check the [flutter secure storage](https://pub.flutter-io.cn/packages/flutter_secure_storage) and there is no implementation for the web yet. check this [issue](https://github.com/mogol/flutter_secure_storage/issues/96), maybe this will help you.

Comment: This is an old question, but I'm hoping this might help anyone searching on Google for same issue. You can follow [this article](https://medium.com/@mayur_solanki/flutter-web-formerly-hummingbird-ba52f5135fb0).